# Sequence a group of dates in R

Tags: r

I wish to generate some Tidy data.

26 companies are observed everyday for 10 days.
Each day a value is recorded.

The first day is: 2020/1/1

How do I create a list of dates so that the first 26 rows of the date column of the date frame is "2020/1/1" (Year, Month, Day) and the next 26 rows are "2020/1/2" etc.

Here is the data frame without the date column:

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(33)

date_chunk <- rep(as.Date("2020/1/1"), 26)

# Tidy data. 10 sequential days starting 2020/1/1/
df <- tibble(
  company = rep(letters, 10),
  value = sample(0:5, 260, replace = TRUE),
  color = "grey"
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
rep(seq(as.Date("2020-01-01"),as.Date("2020-01-10"),1),each=26)
```

This will return a list of dates from 2020-01-01 to 2020-01-10 where each date will be repeated 26 times

Answer (score 1):

For each `company` we can add `row_number()` to `first` `date_chunk` to get an incremental sequence of dates.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(company) %>%
  mutate(date = first(date_chunk) + row_number() - 1)
```

Comment: But I need the dates to increment by one day for each chunk of 26 rows.

Comment: Yes, corrected. Why do you have same date repeated 26 times?

Comment: I'm simulating Tidy data where company and date are column headings. So if there are many companies observed on each day, the date gets repeated. It's more ggplot friendly than human friendly.

Comment: I think you're off by one. Company "z" never gets 2020-01-01.

Comment: You are right. However, now I think this should be done on per company basis instead of repeating date every 26 rows. So later if number of company increases/decreases you don't need to count how many company are present in your data and repeat the rows accordingly. I have updated the answer according to that.